# Copy into snowflake saving file as octet-strea,

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-storage

have a query here. The goal is to send data from Snowflake to Azure Storageblob using a COPY INTO command. `COPY INTO @AZURE_ML_STAGE FROM ( SELECT * FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."DATA" WHERE _FIVETRAN_DELETED = FALSE ) FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=csv)`

Inspite of mentioning `FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=csv)` the data in our Azure storage blob is saved as octet-stream and the file has no .csv extension.
What could we be possibly doing wrong?
Any leads would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From doc: [TYPE = CSV](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#type-csv)

> If the SINGLE copy option is TRUE, then the COPY command unloads a file without a file extension by default. **To specify a file extension, provide a file name and extension in the internal_location or external_location path.** For example:
>
> copy into @stage/data.csv ...
>
> Default: null, **meaning the file extension is determined by the format type, e.g. .csv[compression]**, where compression is the extension added by the compression method, if COMPRESSION is set.

And:

```
COPY INTO @AZURE_ML_STAGE/output.csv
FROM ( SELECT * FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."DATA" 
       WHERE _FIVETRAN_DELETED = FALSE ) 
FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=csv)
COMPRESSION = NONE
SINGLE = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps in saving as .csv file but the contents of the file are all encrypted

Comment: i am trying  `COPY INTO @ML_STAGE/output.csv FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM  "DB"."SCHEMA"."DATA"
    WHERE _FIVETRAN_DELETED = FALSE
  )
  FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV)      
  MAX_FILE_SIZE=1000777216
  SINGLE=TRUE
  HEADER=TRUE
  OVERWRITE=TRUE`

Comment: @Antulii Encrypted or compressed? If Compression is not setup to NONE then it is compressed as compresion default is AUTO and the name should be rather output.csv.gz

Comment: Ok it works with Compression  = None, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Antulii Great to hear it:) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work